# How to render HTML view with parameters using ExpressJS (on the home/root view)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like send a parameter and render a html file when the user go to the home page of my app.

Here is what I did so far:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Hi !'); // never displayed
    res.render('index', { foobar: 'foobar'});
});
```

The HTML is properly rendered (probably due to `express.static`) but `app.get('/')` seems to be never called so I can't return the variable.

How can I return a variable from a call to '/' with the static HTML page *public/index.html*?

My ultimate goal is to be able to use `foobar` in my JS without any additional call to the server. Could you help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file named `index.html` in your `public/` directory, `express.static()` will return that file if the url `/` is requested, so your route handler will never get passed the request.

Generally, templates are stored in a separate directory than static (public) resources. Express, by default, will look for templates in the `./views` directory (unless you tell it otherwise) so if you move your `index.html` to there it will get rendered by EJS (but see below), and you can use your parameters in it.

Since EJS will by default look for files ending with a `.ejs` extension, if you want to keep on using `.html`, you need to set up Express as follows:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
...
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
```

This tells Express to look for files with extension `.html` in the `./views` directory, and to render those files using EJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'));

});



module.exports = router;
```